# How to set Autohotkey Gui control type slider as float?

Tags: autohotkey

By default, the Gui control type "Slider" is ment to be used with integers:

```
Gui, Add, Slider, range0-10, 0
```

But what if I want to use it with floating point numbers? I did some research on the internet and found something known as `Tickinterval`, which should set the value of how much the Slider increases or decreases every tick. So I've tried:

```
Gui, Add, Slider, range0-10 Tickinterval0.1, 0
```

But this had no effect at all. This is why I think the Slider only works with integers. Even though there's no mention of it on the official docs: [Autohotkey GUI Control Types#Slider](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Slider)

Is there any way to make the Slider work with floating point numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching around some more I've found a solution (or workaround) to the problem:

```
Gui, Add, Slider, vSlider gSlide range0-10 tickinterval1-100 AltSubmit, 0

Slide:
    Gui,Submit,NoHide
    int := slider/10
    fra := Mod(int, 10)
    fra := SubStr(fra, InStr(fra,".")+1, 1 )
    val :=  Floor(int) "." fra
    tooltip % val
    SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, 500
return

RemoveToolTip:
    SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, Off
    ToolTip
return
```

I've edited the solution I found to show the correct tooltip when sliding the bar as well. All that's left to do is set the value of `val` to the correct variable and it works like a charm.